# Как сделать правильный Ajax запрос в WordPress? Нужно ли использовать localize_script()?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Вот смотрите: есть Формы на главной странице, их 2 штуки.

1 форма просит номер телефона и имя.

Еще 1 форма обрабатывается уже другим обработчиком.

Обработчики находятся в файле ajax.php, оба в одном файле.

js с ajax обоих форм находятся в разных файлах

custom.js - тут находится только ajax код для 2 формы. Обрабатывается send_order.

main.js - тут находится ajax код для 1 формы. Обрабатывается send_mail. В этом же файле есть и другой код для сайта (возможно, он мешает?).

Сначала у меня не работала и 1-я форма, но когда я после подключения скрипта вписал функцию wp_localize_scipt(), форма заработала. Пытался сделать так же и со второй, не получилось. Вот подключение ниже.

```
wp_enqueue_script('dm-grata-script-main',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js',array('jquery-my'),'',true);
wp_localize_script('dm-grata-script-main','myAjax',array(
    'url'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=send_mail'),
    'nonce'=>wp_create_nonce(),
));
wp_enqueue_script('dm-grata-script-custom',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js',array('jquery-my'),'',true);

wp_localize_script('dm-grata-script-custom','myAjax2',array(
    'url2'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=send_order'),
    'nonce2'=>wp_create_nonce(),
));
```

Вот обработчики. Файл подключается к functions.php

```
<?php 
function send_mail() {

  /* Забираем отправленные данные */
  $client_name  = $_POST['client_name'];
  $client_phone = $_POST['client_phone'];

  /* Отправляем нам письмо */
  $emailTo  = 'grayd2@yandex.ru';
  $subject  = 'Test mail рассылки!';
  $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"";
  $mailBody = "$client_name <br/><br/> $client_phone";

  wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $mailBody, $headers);

  /* Создаем новый пост-письмо */
  $post_data = array(
   'post_title'    => $client_name,
   'post_content'  => $client_phone,
   'post_status'   => 'publish',
   'post_author'   => 1,
   'post_type'     => 'mail',
  );

  wp_insert_post( $post_data );

  /* Завершаем выполнение ajax */
  die();

}

add_action("wp_ajax_send_mail", "send_mail");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_send_mail", "send_mail");
```

Как вы видите, там два обработчика, первый работает. Массив $_POST не пустой и там есть все данные, которые мне нужны.

Но почему-то у 2-го обработчика, который send_order, массив $_POST пустой.

Вот второй

```
function send_order() {

  /* Забираем отправленные данные */
  $client_name_ord   = $_POST['client_name_ord'];
  $client_phone_ord  = $_POST['client_phone_ord'];
  $client_course_ord = $_POST['client_course_ord'];
  print_r($_POST);
  /* Отправляем нам письмо */
  $emailTo  = 'grayd2@yandex.ru';
  $subject  = 'Test mail рассылки!';
  $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"";
  $mailBody = "$client_name_ord <br/><br/> $client_phone_ord <br/><br/> $client_course_ord";

  wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $mailBody, $headers);

  /* Создаем новый пост-письмо */
  $post_data = array(
   'post_title'    => $client_name,
   'post_content'  => $client_phone,
   'post_status'   => 'publish',
   'post_author'   => 1,
   'post_type'     => 'orders',
  );
  wp_insert_post( $post_data );

  /* Завершаем выполнение ajax */
  die();

}

add_action("wp_ajax_send_order", "send_order");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_send_order", "send_order");
?>
```

Вот js второй формы. ее обработчик возвращает пустой массив $_POST.

```
$('.ajax-form-inp-btn-2').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
var orderForm = $('#take_form');
var formDataOrder = {
    client_name_ord:$('.ajax-form-inp-name-2').prop('value'),
    client_phone_ord:$('.ajax-form-inp-phone-2').prop('value'),
    client_course_ord:$('.ajax-form-inp-course-2').prop('value'),
    nonce:myAjax2.nonce2,
};
console.log(formDataOrder);
    $.ajax({
        url: myAjax2.url2,
        data: orderForm,
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function () {
           orderForm.addClass('is-sending');
        },
        error: function (request, txtstatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(request);
           console.log(txtstatus);
           console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (res) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
});
```

Вот js первой формы. Она работает.

```
          $(document).on('submit', '.ajax-form-1', function (e) {
                var formData = {
                  client_name: $('.ajax-form-inp-phone-1').prop('value'),
                  client_phone: $('.ajax-form-inp-name-1').prop('value'),
                  nonce:myAjax.nonce,
                };
                console.log(formData);
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: myAjax.url,
                  data: formData,
                  beforeSend: function () {
                    form.addClass('is-sending');
                  },
                  error: function (request, txtstatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(request);
                    console.log(txtstatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                  },
                  success: function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                    form.removeClass('is-sending').addClass('is-sending-complete');
                    form.find('input').val('');
                    form.find('textarea').val('');

                    setTimeout(function(){
                     form.removeClass('is-sending-complete'); 
                    },2000);
                  }
                });

                e.preventDefault();

              });
```

Может, я вообще неправильно делаю что-то? Дайте хотя бы простой пример двух разных ajax форм на одной странице WordPress. Как это делается вообще? Нужен ли там wp_localize_script()? А если нужен, то нужно ли его под каждую ajax форму делать?

ПОМОГИТЕ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во втором js

```
$.ajax({
    url: myAjax2.url2,
    data: formDataOrder, // Здесь у вас ошибка
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function () {
       orderForm.addClass('is-sending');
    },
```

Причина - банальная невнимательность. ajax ни при чем.

В целом всё сделано правильно. Да, можно два `localize_script()`, а можно и в одну переменную `myAjax` всё засунуть. Вот так

```
wp_localize_script( 'dm-grata-script-main', 'myAjax', array(
    'url'    => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=send_mail' ),
    'nonce'  => wp_create_nonce(),
    'url2'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=send_order' ),
    'nonce2' => wp_create_nonce(),
) );
```

И во втором обработчике использовать `myAjax` вместо `myAjax2`. Ведь что делает `localize_script()`? Он выводит `CDATA` с вашей переменной `myAjax` на страницу, посмотрите в исходном коде страницы (Ctrl+U). А скрипт уже подхватывает эту глобальную переменную.

Но для лучшей читаемости кода оставьте так, как есть - с двумя запусками `localize_script()`.

Comment: Я с проблемой разобрался,забыл закрыть вопрос,действительно не внимательность)) .но все равно спасибо вам большое за четкий ответ)